# Cannot resolve method getActivity() in a class extending FragmentActivity

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-toolbar

I have extended Fragment Activity in a class where I also need to have a custom toolbar. So,I added the code to get the toolbar but the setSupportActionBar(toolbar) did not work.Then, I added AppCompatActivity.getActivity() to cast but that did not work as well.

Here is the code -

```
public class main_fragment extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

}
```

Comment: I tried that.Did not work. It shows Cannot resolve symbol for 'ActionBarCompat'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`. The first thing you have to change is

```
extends FragmentActivity
```

with

```
extends AppCompatActivity
```

`getActivity()` is a method of `Fragment`. `Activity` has not that method, so you don't need to call it to use `setSupportActionBar` and `getSupportActionBar`

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Material** way of setting a toolbar.
1/ Declare it in the XML. 
2/ Find it after inflating it in your activity/fragment class. 
3/ Configure title, menu, etc..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your Fragment/Activity find the toolbar.

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.setTitle(/*your title*/);
mToolbar.inflateMenu(/* menu res id here*/);
mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickLister(/*override the click methods with item.getId == your id*/));
```